# Taylor expansion - multiplication of functions

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I've encountered the following statement: Let $f$ and $g$ be analytical functions, then define $k(x) = f(x)g(x)$. Let $g(x) =a_0+ a_1x + a_2\frac{x^2}{2!} +R_2(x)$ be its Taylor expansion at $x=0$. Now they claim that 
$$
k(x)= f(x)a_0+ f(x)a_1x + f(x)a_2\frac{x^2}{2}! +f(x)R_2(x) = T_n(x)+R_n(x).
$$
My question is it true (and why?) that $T_n(x)$ is Taylor expansion of order $n$ of $k(x)$?

Comment: Well the first equality should be rather obvious.  You just multiply $g$ by $f$ directly.  The last equality is a bit hardy and follows from [Cauchy products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series).

Comment: Thank you. I can see why the RHS is a polynomial representation of $k(x)$ but how do I know that it is Taylor expansion and not some other series?

Comment: [Merten's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Proof_of_Mertens.27_theorem) holds your answer.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as stated. What is this $n$ you speak of?